# AWS Mobile Hub: Sample code for web application

Tags: amazon-web-services

I like the friendly interface that AWS Mobile Hub provides to disparate Amazon services, but I'd like to use it to create a web application, rather than a native iOS or Android app.

It's not clear to me how to do so, since there's no option for javascript sample code or any mention of web applications:

[image]

Am I missing something?  Is there documentation for this use-case elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the resources that are configured by various features in Mobile Hub (e.g., NoSQL Database, Cloud Logic APIs) are usable directly from a web app in the browser. For example, you can turn on the App Content Delivery feature, enable web hosting on your Amazon S3 bucket, download/copy the AWS JavaScript SDK into your Amazon S3 bucket, and start writing your web app. The JavaScript SDK will allow you to interact with your Mobile Hub resources (found on the "Resources" page in the left Nav menu in Mobile Hub's console).

However, we do realize these steps are tedious and we have had similar feedback from other customers. So, we are actively working to make these steps easier.

In the meantime, you can get the AWS JavaScript SDK here:
https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

And, you may find some of our github samples are a good starting point, like this one:
https://github.com/awslabs/lambda-refarch-webapp

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to build web apps, AWS has a JavaScript library called AWS Amplify that makes building cloud web apps easy: https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/